# 1x drive conversion

Tags: crankset

I haven't been consistently riding on a trail in a number of years, and I'm a little overwhelmed by the options. So if I could receive a bit of info and an opinion or two it would be greatly appreciated. I recently bought a 2014 GT Karkaram sport that I'd like to spec. Well at least at the moment I'd like to convert its 3x9 drive to a 1x11. Not trying to break the bank, but what I think I've found is the following: all SRAM 1xXSYNC cranks, 1x11 x horizon rear derailleur, nx trigger shifter, PG1130 cassette, and a PC 1110 chain.

Comment: You've bought an entry level mountain bike and want to add some relatively expensive parts. I'd probably just buy a bike spec'd as a 1 x 11 to begin, which will probably come with a better frame and fork; ride the bike as is (with any repairs necessary to make it safe/general upkeep) until you're sure you want to ride again, then sell it and buy something else. Your approach is basically like buying a Honda Civic for 20k and adding 25k worth of parts -- might as well spend the 45k on something else rather than the Civic.

Comment: I really like the frame fit tho.... I understand what your saying. That's why i was thinking the Lower end components......

Comment: Theres really nothing stopping you from doing this (and if you *really* like the frame, maybe its worth it to you personally) ; I just don't see this as a particularly sensible plan, unless the parts pretty cheap and the existing drivetrain is shot (where I'd probably replace it with another 3x8 or 3x9).

Comment: Your money, so spend it how you want, but consider what does 1x 'bring to the table'?  Unless the purpose is to make the bike look more trendy, the money is much better spent elsewhere (e.g. a new wheel set would make a much bigger difference).

Comment: In most cases you could spare the expense of a new crank by just getting a narrow-wide ring and mounting it by itself in the middle position of your existing crank, along with some single ring chainring bolts.

Comment: Voting to leave open because the underlying question is "what needs changing to convert to a 1x setup?"  The specific parts listed are a distraction.

Comment: Don't forget to check and make sure that the freehub can fit an 11 speed cassette before you start buying parts.

Answer (score 1):

I've converted recently.
and used

- a narrow-wide front chain-ring which is about £15-20
- a rear-mech with clutch mechanism £35
- right hand trigger shifter £15

Comment: Don't forget the cassette.

Comment: And a new chain

Answer (score 1):

I might be a litte bit late to reply to your question. Regarding the conversion from 3x9 to 1x11, there is actually an cheaper alternative. As you are using 3x9, there is really no need to get 1x11. I would suggest getting this:

1. Raceface Chain Ring NW
2. Chain Guide (MRP/ Fouriers)

I have a deore 3x9 before and converted to a 1x9 paired with a chain guide and a narrow wide. Of course, I cut short the chain to increase the tension. I am riding a AM hardtail and have never dropped a chain. It is way cheaper and last longer. Also, if you happen to break it, it would be a cheap replacement.

The cost of a chain ring should be about USD25-40 (depends on brands) and chain guide could be USD50-100 (once again, depends on brand). IMHO, there is no need for any 1x11.

In case you are riding what riding I do.. I do mostly urban like 1-3m drops, stairs, gaps, basically urban downhill.

Hope it helps!

Comment: So you save a bit of weight, but loose your 3-5 lowest/climbing gears ?   Did you upsize the cassette too or just don't need the climbing gears ?

Comment: TBH, you don't need much gears on your cassette. 12-34t seem just fine on most trails, it all comes down to your body position and your leg muscles IMO

Answer (score 0):

Those sound about right.  Buy a kit (groupset) is typically cheaper. You can find them on Amazon (and others).  None of the SRAM 1x11 are cheap. The cheapest 1X groupset from SRAM is more than your bike.

The cassette is more a road cassette but you see them on mtn also.

This [link](https://www.sram.com/sram/mountain/family/x01) should help.